# How can we change editor font in octave in ubuntu 18?

Tags: octave

It is very difficult to read the code due to very small font of octave editor. I am unable to find where to change this font setting for editor text.

I am attaching the screenshot of the octave editor platform.

[image: screenshot of the octave editor platform]

I expect to increase my editor font to work properly.Thanks

Comment: see `Edit - Settings - Terminal`

Comment: That is for terminal "command window" font, I'm talking about "editor" font

Comment: Edit - Preferences - Editor Styles

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Where would you have expected the menu to change the font if not in "Edit - Preferences"?

Comment: It worked.Thanks @matzeri

Comment: @Andy That's where I expected it to be. Except it's not. There are two, as you can see right on the picture. Perhaps, like me OP wasn't expecting to have to look for a second, context sensitive edit menu button and needed help to find it.

Comment: @matzeri please add your comment in the answer section. I will mark it as a worked solution, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the entire Ubuntu font by

**gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor [font size ]**

Example :
**gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.4**

to know about current font use following command

**gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor**